# "Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component" error with react-native and yarn workspace

Tags: reactjs, react-native, yarnpkg, react-apollo, yarn-workspaces

I am currently developing a project based on a yarn workspace. I had problems all day installing apollo correctly in react-native and finally, I managed to do so by changing the configuration of the metro.config.js file (which I leave below, even if I think it does not affect the problem). However, when I started to implement the @apollo/react-hooks library I encountered the following error:

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

Surfing the internet I came across other similar problems and the official react documentation which says:

```
There are three common reasons you might be seeing it:

- You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.
- You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks.
- You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.
```

I think the second option is excluded regardless since the code that I have implemented is very simple and I think it is impossible that there is an error. Even the first option seems impossible to me since I am using react-native and therefore I am not using the React DOM module (and apologize for my ignorance if I am wrong in this).

The last option is the most accredited one. In fact, checking the two node_modules folders (the one at the root of the workspace and the one in the mobile app package) I realized that the "react" module is present in both directories.

By making attempts, I realized that the react module is installed twice only when the "nohoist" property is used in the package.json file of the react-native application. As soon as I insert the react-native module in the "nohoist" array, react is also installed in the "local" node_modules folder and also in the one at the root of the project.

```
  "workspaces": {
    "nohoist": [
      "react-native",   <---------
      "react-native/**",  <---------
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl",
      "@react-native-mapbox-gl/**",
      "react-native-gesture-handler",
      "react-native-gesture-handler/**",
      "react-native-reanimated",
      "react-native-reanimated/**",
      "@react-navigation",
      "@react-navigation/**",
      "react-native-safe-area-context",
      "react-native-safe-area-context/**",
      "react-native-vector-icons",
      "react-native-vector-icons/**",
      "react-native-pose",
      "react-native-pose/**",
      "@react-native-community",
      "@react-native-community/**",
      "react-native-elements",
      "react-native-elements/**"
    ]
  }
```

I can't understand how the "react-native" module also affects the "react" module. I suppose the solution here is to prevent this from happening, but I don't know how.

This is the *metro.config.js* file (in case anyone wants to check it, even if I don't think it's connected with this problem):

```
const path = require("path");
const getWorkspaces = require("get-yarn-workspaces");
const blacklist = require("metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist");

const workspaces = getWorkspaces(__dirname);

module.exports = {
  projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, "."),

  watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname, "../../node_modules"), ...workspaces],

  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist(
      workspaces.map(
        (workspacePath) =>
          `/${workspacePath.replace(
            /\//g,
            "[/\\\\]",
          )}[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\]react-native[/\\\\].*/`,
      ),
    ),
    extraNodeModules: {
      "react-native": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/react-native"),
    },
  },
};
```

Instead, this is the file where the error came from:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {View, Text, Button} from "react-native";
import {StackScreenProps} from "@react-navigation/stack";
import {AuthStackParamList} from "../../../navigation";
import {useRegisterMutation} from "../../../generated/graphql";
import {InputText} from "../../../components/InputText";

type SignUpScreenProps = StackScreenProps<AuthStackParamList, "SignUp">;

export const SignUpScreen: React.FC<SignUpScreenProps> = ({navigation}) => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");


  const [signup] = useRegisterMutation();
  

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const {data, errors} = await signup({
      variables: {username, email, password},
    });
    console.log(data, errors);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
      <Text>SignUp</Text>
      <InputText
        label="Username"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={setUsername}
        textContentType="username"
      />
      <InputText
        label="Email"
        value={email}
        onChangeText={setEmail}
        textContentType="emailAddress"
      />
      <InputText
        label="Email"
        value={password}
        onChangeText={setPassword}
        textContentType="password"
        secureTextEntry
      />
      <Button title="Crea account" onPress={handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Thanks in advance to all of you.

**Update:**

By adding "react" to the "nohoist" field in the package.json at the root of the workspace, I have solved (for now) the error. However, I am convinced that the problem will return when I add a web app (reactjs) to the workspace. So if anyone has a better solution is undoubtedly accepted.

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react",
      "**/react/**"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.20.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

Please import useMutation

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
```

use like this

```
const [signup] = useMutation(useRegisterMutation)
```

Now you have to call

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const {data, errors} = await signup({
      variables: {username, email, password},
    });
    console.log(data, errors);
  };
```

For more info here is the [Link](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usemutation)

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention to my problem, however, I believe that this is not the cause of the error. For my mistake, I forgot to write that I am using a package called @graphql-codegen/cli which automatically generates hooks for the query defined in a schema. In this case the "useRegisterMutation" function is imported from a file that is then self-generated. I have also tried to follow your approach, and I continue to receive the same error.